# Watson internet of things platform: not able to assign standard gateway role to a device

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I am trying to assign standard gateway role to a gateway device as per docs available 
https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002-beta/security-gateway-beta.html#!/Limited_Gateway/put_authorization_devices_deviceId_roles

But I keep on getting 403 Forbidden error. I am using app credentials (api key and token) which has "Operations application" role and hence privileges to assign roles.

Here are few scripts which are run, where I have replaced org, type, id and token with dummy values

```
curl -X PUT \
 https://dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:443/api/v0002/authorization/devices/g%3Adummyorg%3Adummytype%3Adummyid/roles \
      -H 'authorization: Basic dummyauth' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{
      "roles": [
        {
          "roleId": "PD_STANDARD_GW_DEVICE",
          "roleStatus": 1
        }
      ]
    }'
```

Response
HTTP 403 forbidden

When I try to get the role of device, it works fine

```
curl -X GET \
  https://dummyorg.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:443/api/v0002/authorization/devices/g%3Adummyorg%3Adummytype%3Adummyid/roles \
  -H 'authorization: Basic dummyauth' \
```

Response

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "roleId": "PD_PRIVILEGED_GW_DEVICE",
      "roleStatus": 1
    }
  ],
  "rolesToGroups": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the url - you have to use the 'g' and you have to encode it. You need to include a Basic Authorisation header which has your API keys (mine are Standard Application):

```
PUT /api/v0002/authorization/devices/g%3AOrgID%3Agatewaytype%3AmyGateway/roles HTTP/1.1
Host: OrgID.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
Authorization: Basic removed
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: removed

{  
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleId": "PD_STANDARD_GW_DEVICE",
            "roleStatus": 1         
        }
    ],  
    "rolesToGroups": {}
}
```

Comment: @amadmin: I have added scripts which I use. I use g: instead of d: & also API keys for Operation application which has much more priviliges

Comment: I'm on Windows, curl makes me suffer for anything more than a simple GET.  I tried, but it gives 'CUDAS0002E: An IO error occurred while processing the response.' I also tried RestClient in Firefox and that worked perfect.